# RichEditBox loses formatting for empty text

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

I have something like a diagramming UWP application where each shape has an RichEditBox. The problem is, that I loose the formatting when the text is empty.

For Example:

1. Change the text to bold: EditBox.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat.Bold = FormatEffect.On.
2. Delete all text
3. Get the text via "EditBox.Document.GetText(GetTextFormat.FormatRtf, out text);

=> The result is just an empty string, not valid RTF document at all. This is a problem in my scenario. Is there an approach to solve it? I think RichEditBox should always provide a valid RTF document.

Comment: `EditBox.Document.Selection.GetText(GetTextFormat.FormatRtf, out text);` This method is to get selected text. If you delete all, no text is selected, the result is off course empty string. What's the result you want for this method after no text selected?

Comment: I was meanng the GetText method from the ITextDocument class, I fixed my post.

Comment: Then, I cannot reproduce your problem. See [this picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhv77.png) about the `GetText` result after delete all text.